# Drupal 7 noob questions: allowing users to access forms and user uploading files

Tags: file-upload, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I would likely to preface this post by saying that I am extremely new to Drupal 7 and so far have just gone through the book Drupal 7 Module Development and a few online tutorials.

I am trying to make a webpage that allows user to upload and view collections of data.  These collections will consist of a screenshot, a description of their collection and a collection of XML files.  I would like the user to be able to upload a .zip file through a form and then have that zip get seperated and added to the main page which will show all of the collections with their screenshots and descriptions.

So far I have found a couple tutorial that helped me get a basic file upload going but it was never quite what I wanted.  In the example I created from the tutorial I created a new content type and a form and I can now click on add content which will bring up my form that allows me to upload an image file which will be associated with my content type.  What I could never quite figure out was how I would get a form like this to show up on a page that the user can access (instead of popping up after selecting add content which seems to be only usable by administrators).  I would like to have a page that shows my gallery with a button that would take the user to a form they could use to upload their content.

Can anyone explain how I would do this or maybe point me at some better tutorials/example that I may have missed.  Also, are there any good modules that might be a good starting point for this type of endeavor?

Answer (score 1):

Probably I don't know what you are trying to do entirely... but uploading the XML file, setting the description and uploading the Image, separately, all as a content type, is far easy to implement than uploading a .ZIP file split it in server and save it.

Then, to allow users to upload files you must config the permissions and roles. Do you want anonymous users to upload files? If not, you must set roles and registration preferences.

It seems to me that you can do what you want without coding.

I suggest you these links to start learning with Drupal:

http://gotdrupal.com/

http://learnbythedrop.com/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ah sweet thanks, I see that if I set permissions for new content type it will show up under add content but how would I instead allow this content to pop up when I press a button on page instead of going through add content?

Comment: Also, it would be important for me to be able to upload a single zip file and handle that automatically at some point but I can figure that out in a future iteration.

Comment: You should try setting primary or secondary links (search for menus) to define a better navigation. Also you can place these menus as blocks anywhere on your template based on certain paths or conditions.

Comment: Uploading a Zip file and split it after is not impossible but you should probably write custom code for this functionality. I come from D6 and I had not seen a module that does that job... so probably it's not in D7.

Answer (score 1):

Link is easy, just copy the URL path to the add content page and use it as a link - making sure that your users have 'permission' to 'create #content type' and 'edit own #content type" in the permissions area under users. A word of warning - if you offer this to anon users you **will** get spammed so make sure you have mollom (nice) or kaptcha installed as well.

Beto is right too, you can add the links once you have the url to navigation menus.

For zip file you can define what files are allowable in an upload field in your content type and restrict down to zips and set a maxiumum upload size (highly recommended!). Later on you can use views module to display lists of titles and links etc on pages - that's your future learning project :-)